# How do multiple copies of creatures with activated abilities interact?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Anointed Chorister](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAnointed%20Chorister%5d) has the activated ability:

> {4}{W}: Anointed Chorister gets +3/+3 until end of turn.

If I have two or more copies of this creature in play on the battlefield and pay the cost to activate this ability, will that one time payment of 4 colorless and 1 white mana activate the other copies as well, without spending more mana, or would I need to spend another 4 colorless and 1 white mana to get the other copies to trigger?

Comment: Welcome to the site! I've taken the liberty of suggesting and edit with a title that makes it easier to see what your question is about; if you prefer, you can [edit] the title yourself.

Comment: The part of the linked question about Vector Asp addresses the same issue that this question is about.

Comment: Thank you for your time and clarification on the title. I am grateful.